# How to add shard id to ShardIdentifierProvider?

Tags: hibernate-search

I configured ShardIdProvider with properties file.

```
hibernate.search.default.sharding_strategy=com.sodonsolution.portalcms3.search.SiteIdAsShardIdProvider
```

Then I need to add shard id while running. `ShardIdentifierProviderTemplate.addShard` method exist but how can I access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is: you don't need to call that method, at least not from outside the shard identifier provider: it's all automatic.

Long answer: shards are supposed to be added automatically whenever the first entity in a shard is discovered.

That's why the `addShard` method is `protected`: it is only called from within the shard identifier provider, like this:

```
public static class SiteIdShardIdentifierProvider extends ShardIdentifierProviderTemplate {

    @Override
    public String getShardIdentifier(Class<?> entityType, Serializable id, String idAsString, Document document) {
        if ( entityType.equals( MyEntityAssociatedWithASite.class ) ) {
            final String siteId = document.getField( "site.id" ).stringValue();
            addShard( siteId );
            return siteId;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException( "MyEntityAssociatedWithASite expected but found " + entityType );
    }
}
```

Judging from the name of your shard identifier provider, it uses the site ID as shard ID (something along the lines of my example above), so you shouldn't need to do anything to add a new shard: it should be added as soon as you index a new entity with a new site ID. If this doesn't work, there may be an issue with the code of your shard identifier provider.

See also the Hibernate Search documentation, which explains how `ShardIdentifierProviderTemplate` works: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#advanced-features-dynamic-sharding